# Spring MVC Controller mapping regex

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My controller mappings:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{objectId}/{objectName: [a-zA-Z-]+}", method = GET)
public String getObjects(@PathVariable Integer objectId, Model model) { ... }

@RequestMapping(value = "{objectId}/{objectName: [a-zA-Z-]+}_{category}", method = GET)
public String getObjectsForCategories(@PathVariable Integer objectId, 
                                      @PathVariable String category, 
                                      Model model) { ... }
```

And the urls I'm hitting:

> http://localhost:8080/objects/2/xyz
>
> http://localhost:8080/objects/2/xyz_mobile

Spring unable to find the handler and complains with No mapping found for HTTP request.

Comment: Remove the space between `:` and `regex` and Try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Spring MVC documentation:](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex)

> The `@RequestMapping` annotation supports the use of regular expressions
>   in URI template variables. The syntax is `{varName:regex}` where the
>   first part defines the variable name and the second - the regular
>   expression.

So, you should remove the space between `:` and `regex`, like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{objectId}/{objectName:[a-zA-Z-]+}", method = GET)
                                                ^ Space is removed
```